# Different definitions of an affine algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Hartshorne assumes we are working over an algebraically closed field $k$ and we simply define algebraic sets to be any set of the form $V(I)\subset k^n$, where $I\subset k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is an ideal.

Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves extends the definition to non-algebraically closed fields, by looking at a field $k$ and its algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ and distinguishing between sets $V(I)\subset \overline{k}^n$, where $I$ can be generated by polynomials in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ vs. only by a family of polynomials in $\overline{k}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. In the former case he says that $V(I)$ is *defined over $K$*. He needs this to do arithmetic and work over $k=\mathbb{Q}$.

Now another interesting case I found is given by the notes of Steven Shatz and Jean Gallier (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/algeom/steve01.html). Here the definition is the following:

Let $k$ be any field and $\Omega/k$ an extension of $k$ s.t.

1. $\Omega$ is algebraically closed.
2. $\textrm{tr.deg}_k \Omega =\aleph_0$.

They define $\mathbb{A}^n=\Omega^k$. And say that the *$k$-topology on $\mathbb{A}^n$* is the topology where closed sets are of the form $V(I)$ with $I\subset k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ an ideal and the *Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^n$* is the topology with $I\subset \overline{k}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$.

My question is the following: What is the gain of the more complicated definition in the Shatz, Gallier book? Why is it not enough to just take the algebraic closure?

Comment: I'm largely ignorant about algebraic geometry, but IIRC the point of using $\Omega$ (proposed by Weil?) was to get *generic points* to come out naturally. Somebody who knows this stuff once explained to me that using the language of schemes (i.e. the way Hartshorne does it) is thought to be better by most of modern practitioners. I guess because then you can do things like define objects over $\Bbb{Z}$ and have the ability to move to fields of different characteristics. $\Omega$ doesn't give you that kind of a freedom. +1 for I want to see a real answer to this question, too!

Comment: There's a theorem that involves generic points that I haven't seen in any other elementary coverage in the Shatz, Gallier text. The book starts by doing the classical machinery with this setup and then moves to schemes.